# Return a list or array with different model types

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have the following code:

```
        BandProfileModel BandProfile;
        MusicanProfileModel MusicanProfile;
        RegularProfileModel RegularProfile;

        using (AppDbContext ctx = new AppDbContext())
        {
            var rolesForUser = userManager.GetRoles(UserId);
            if(rolesForUser.Count() <= 0)
            {
                return View("SetupNewProfile");
            }

            //This below don't work: Canno't implicity convert type "System.Linq.IQueryable"....
            BandProfile = ctx.BandProfiles.Where(u => u.UserId == UserId);
            MusicanProfile = ctx.MusicanProfiles.Where(u => u.UserId == UserId);
            RegularProfile = ctx.RegularProfiles.Where(u => u.UserId == UserId);
        }

        return View(Profiles);
```

I want to merge the BandProfile, MusicanProfile and RegularProfile into an Array or List and return it to the view, but I don't know how to do It.

How can I merge different class/model types into one Array/list?

Comment: You can use a `List<object>`, but how do you expect the view to be able to consume this list? You can create a model class that contain the three lists as properties. That might be a better thing to do.

Comment: create anonymous object like `.Select(x=>new{ UserId=x.UserId });` Now you can use `Concat/Union`.

Comment: Do these classes have any sort of inheritance going on?

Comment: @YacoubMassad: I want to loop through this Array/list in the view.

Comment: Why not have three loops? You need to handle each type differently, right?

Comment: @YacoubMassad: Yeah, first I had Three loops, but now I want just one.

Comment: Can you show you do you consume the list in the View?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an abstraction for these types, you could return a list of this abstraction. It could be an `interface` or a `abstract class` or even a simples `class` that all types inherit. The option could be to return a collection of `System.Object` (.net) or `object` (in C#). For sample

```
var result = new List<object>();

using (AppDbContext ctx = new AppDbContext())
{
    var rolesForUser = userManager.GetRoles(UserId);
    if(rolesForUser.Count() <= 0)
    {
        return View("SetupNewProfile");
    }

    var bandProfile = ctx.BandProfiles.Where(u => u.UserId == UserId).ToList();
    var musicanProfile = ctx.MusicanProfiles.Where(u => u.UserId == UserId).ToList();
    var regularProfile = ctx.RegularProfiles.Where(u => u.UserId == UserId).ToList();

    result.AddRange(BandProfile);
    result.AddRange(MusicanProfile);
    result.AddRange(RegularProfile);    
}

return View(result);
```

Using a `object` you have to check and convert (cast) the type to read all properties or call method from the object. Follow the `OOP` (short for `Oriented Object Programming`), you could have a abstract type to hold all comom properties/methods you need into a single type. Doing something like this, you could convert the result of your lists into this abstract type and use it on the View to have a strongly typed view. For sample:

Let's supose you have this classe:

```
public class Profile 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You could have classes iheriting from it or converting to it.

Another option could be casting your queries to return this type.

```
var result = new List<Profile>();

using (AppDbContext ctx = new AppDbContext())
{
    var rolesForUser = userManager.GetRoles(UserId);
    if(rolesForUser.Count() <= 0)
    {
        return View("SetupNewProfile");
    }


    var bandProfile = ctx.BandProfiles.Where(u => u.UserId == UserId)
                                      .Select(x => new Profile() { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name})
                                      .ToList();


    var musicanProfile = ctx.MusicanProfiles.Where(u => u.UserId == UserId)
                                      .Select(x => new Profile() { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name})
                                      .ToList();


    var regularProfile = ctx.RegularProfile.Where(u => u.UserId == UserId)
                                      .Select(x => new Profile() { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name})
                                      .ToList();


    result.AddRange(BandProfile);
    result.AddRange(MusicanProfile);
    result.AddRange(RegularProfile);    
}

return View(result);
```

Comment: Thank you. this worked. Would you solved like this? Or would you do It in Another way? What do you mean with If I have an abstraction for these types?

Comment: @Bryan see my updates. You could have a base class or convert everything into a single type and have a strongly typed view.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by creating a new class that contains the properties common to all three entities. Then you can select a projection of the entity to the new class.

If your new class looks like this:

```
public class Profile
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can select like this:

```
BandProfile = ctx.BandProfiles.Where(u => u.UserId == UserId).Select(x => new Profile(){Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name}).ToList();

MusicanProfile = ctx.MusicanProfiles.Where(u => u.UserId == UserId).Select(x => new Profile(){Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name}).ToList();

RegularProfile = ctx.RegularProfiles.Where(u => u.UserId == UserId).Select(x => new Profile(){Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name}).ToList();
```

Then you should be able to merge those 3 collections into a single list and return it in the View. This can also have the added benefit of not returning more data to the client than you intended because only properties explicitly added to the Profile class will be returned.

Comment: And what type should the list be?

Comment: @Bryan - it should be a list of type Profile or whatever you call the class. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this considered best practice? Would you solve It this way or in Another way?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can call it best practice but there are benefits to this.If you use a DTO class to project your query results into you might see performance benefits because it's quite possible you will not have to select as much data from the database and there is less for the framework to load into the entity class. Also, it's possible there are some fields you'd prefer to not make it to the view or you might want to tweak the query results. This is a nice way of handling this.